# Can this Cartesian product question be answered with Venn diagrams?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Is $(A \cap B) \times C = (A \times C) \cap (B \times C)$ true for all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$? If so, prove it. If not, give an example of sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ for which it is false.

Simply put, can this be solved using Venn diagrams? If not, what method can I use to solve it? I understand that $A \times C = \{(a,c) \mid a \in A, c \in C\}$ but I still don't really understand how to solve a question like this.

Answer (score 2):

Proving/disproving it directly would be easier than using a Venn diagram.

Suppose $(x,y) \in (A \cap B) \times C$. Then $y \in C$ and $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$. Since $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$, we can say that $(x,y) \in (A \times C)$ and $(x,y) \in (B \times C)$. So $(x,y) \in (A \times C) \cap (B \times C)$. This shows that $(A \cap B) \times C \subseteq (A \times C) \cap (B \times C)$

Demonstrating the converse, $(A \cap B) \times C \supseteq (A \times C) \cap (B \times C)$ , is done similarly.